# Dblink Insert Update Delete - Number of rows affected always zero

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-view, dblink

I'm using `dblink` to do some data manipulation (insert, update or delete) on a remote database. Specifically I am using views, and rules on the views to do the insert, update or delete. For example:

```sql
-- SQL
-- Note: get_remote_db() is a function returning the connection string

CREATE VIEW remote_table AS
SELECT * FROM dblink(get_remote_db(), 'SELECT id, name FROM example_table')
AS rec(id NUMERIC, name VARCHAR);

CREATE RULE remote_table_update AS
ON UPDATE TO remote_table DO INSTEAD
SELECT dblink_exec(
    get_remote_db(),
    concat('UPDATE example_table SET name = ', quote_nullable(NEW.name),
        ' WHERE id = ', quote_nullable(OLD.id)),
    true);
```

```java
// Java

String SQL = "UPDATE remote_table SET name = 'John' WHERE id = 23";
int iRowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate(SQL);
if (iRowsAffected > 0) {
    System.out.println("Rows affected: " + iRowsAffected);
} else {
    System.out.println("No rows affected!");
}
```

I find that when using `dblink_exec` the number of rows affected is always zero, even if in the remote database, some rows (more than zero) are affected.

Is there any workaround to this? Parts of my application are dependent on getting the number of rows affected. If the number is always zero, the application will not work as intended.

**Clarification:** The update statement in the Java code activates the rule and performs the update correctly. There is no issue there. The issue is with the value of `iRowsAffected`, which is always zero even if a row was updated.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your view is not "simple" as defined by the [documantation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html) and therefore not update-able.

> Simple views are automatically updatable: the system will allow INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements to be used on the view in the same way as on a regular table. A view is automatically updatable if it satisfies all of the following conditions:
>
> The view must have exactly one entry in its FROM list, which must be a table or another updatable view.
>
> The view definition must not contain WITH, DISTINCT, GROUP BY, HAVING, LIMIT, or OFFSET clauses at the top level.
>
> The view definition must not contain set operations (UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT) at the top level.
>
> All columns in the view's select list must be simple references to columns of the underlying relation. They cannot be expressions, literals or functions. System columns cannot be referenced, either.
>
> No column of the underlying relation can appear more than once in the view's select list.
>
> The view must not have the security_barrier property.

[Common Table Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) in PostgreSQL would be a better choice here.

Comment: The view is updatable. I mentioned in the question that there are changes being made. The issue is not that I can't update the view - I can. The issue is the number of rows affected is always returned as zero, which is incorrect. So your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Also, the DB in use is 9.1, where simple views are not updatable. Updatable views are only introduced in 9.3. Your blanket statement that any view that is not simple is not updatable is also wrong. Complex views are not *automatically* updatable but they can be made manually updatable using triggers or rules (and if you noticed, I used a rule). Finally, I have no idea how CTE are supposed to help here - they seem completely unrelated to the problem at hand.